# Apps for having kids sequence letters that are part of words

Tags: android, educational, accessibility, children, writing

Apps exist that introduce the child to each letter by presenting the letter and sounding out each letter name and having the child trace out the letter, even as part of an interactive game with funny characters interacting with the child (such as the [this funny food letter app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.arrowstar.funnyfood4) Android app by [Wow Kids](https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=7563190634447240733).

Those games are great, and are good for three or four year olds and upwards.

However, once they turn five and upwards, they may need to engage in word letter sequencing, that is, putting letters one after the other in sequence (as some sort of simplified Scrabble for young learners including those with difficulties).

For children that have a need to do things quickly, move quickly, and say, things, they need to put out, quickly (with an arm gesture movement that puts into place, the stuff, that goes in the right place, making the sound of the letter and making it part of the word it is part of).

I may be wrong, but, according to the type of difficulty or disability, if present, the child may need something to waste some time, while moving, e.g., scrolling the finger, to, select the letter, that needs to be placed in the sequence next, searching, as when they will need to write with a pen, the right word (and might need to be a bit patient and devote some time to thinking about the letter and tracing it out in terms of the letters that make it up, by dragging the letters).

I was thinking about an app that works as follows:

The parents can input the words, remotely, and control the presentation list. One word at a time is presented.

The child holds the phone, possibly, in landscape mode.

There are three rows.

The first row, presents the word. Each letter in the word shows up with a different color coded foreground and background color, only common to letters that are the same. This can be turned off so that all letters have the same foreground and background.

The second row, is a grid, where the child must drag the letters, to place them one after the other. Optionally, the child may just click the letter to place it.

The letters, appear, from the whole alphabet, placed alphabetically, in the third row. These are the ones that can be dragged to the second row.

Such letters in the third row may either appear in alphabetical order or in a randomly scrambled order that changes with each new word presented.

This way, the child, learns, to recognize letters, and compose words.

This app would also be great for children with disabilities or difficulties, who have already learned to trace out and recognize the letters, but now must place them one after another to make up words.

Thank you for implementing this app,

or for directing me to where I can find one with this functionality.

It would also be great if the list from the parents could be input from the other phone, but the child then had to select the letters to spell the word out, after merely hearing the sound (the sound button could be pressed various times to make the word heard).

This would be enough for some phonetic languages where letters correspond to sounds in a one to one fashion (such as Italian Spanish, Korean, Japanese, Czech, and others).

But for languages such as English, the user needs to view a pattern word with a specific sound spelling.

When presented a different word, they need to be given words, either in writing, or, with a microphone hinting button that when pressed sounds out the similar word, so that the learner can make out that it is spelled the same, before spelling it. Is it not so?

For instance, the Merriam Webster has a phonetics section, but what if a word follows a French pattern of pronunciation or an old Gaelic pattern in the etymology of the word, that helps you understand why the word is spelled out that way. Could a child learn etymology, alongside the words? And would they need to be multilingual to spell better? How would you do this?

And why isn't there an Education Stack Exchange.

Can anyone please suggest a good app?

That can deal with these issues, and make the best, for teaching, how to spell.

It would be nice to have an international app that allowed you to sequence words in any language (you could select the language in language settings).

Pictures next to letters, for instance, by presenting, a letter, with a picture of an image whose word starts with that letter, as used in preschool, I think are very useful for learning those letters.

However, pictures next to words are needed to have the stuff the word describes described in a picture (or, even more than one picture if stuff like verb tenses are also to be illustrated).

Perhaps we need a standardized set of pictures for each word in the dictionary, so users (especially young can recognize word meaning (and learn words, including their spelling, from any language).

What has been done in these areas?

Thank you for your thoughts and implementations.

Thank you for your contributions.

Can you please point me to any app that does what I describe (and could be useful to a child to lean to spell and write, in any language)?

Thanks.